# Yii2 - Update data by switch toogle using Ajax/Pjax in GridView

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2, pjax

I want to update my data in GridView using Switch Toogle without refresh the current page.
Here is the image:
[image: img1]

So I want to update the attribute `status` using the toogle switch like the image above.
Here is my code:

index.php

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        //'alumni_id',
        'tahun_lulus',
        'file_excel',
        [
            'attribute' => 'status',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($data){
                if($data->status==0){
                    return SwitchInput::widget([
                        'name' => 'status_11',
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'size' => 'mini',
                            'onColor' => 'success',
                            'offColor' => 'danger',
                            'onText' => 'Active',
                            'offText' => 'Inactive',
                        ],
                        'value' => true,
                    ]);
                }
                else if($data->status==1){
                    return SwitchInput::widget([
                        'name' => 'status_11',
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'size' => 'mini',
                            'onColor' => 'success',
                            'offColor' => 'danger',
                            'onText' => 'Active',
                            'offText' => 'Inactive',
                        ],
                        'value' => false,
                    ]);;
                }
            }
        ],
        //'deleted',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',

        [ 'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

How can I do that with Ajax/Pjax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I suggest you the solution there is something you need to fix as you have redundant code inside the `GridView` that is below.

```
[
    'attribute' => 'status',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function($data){
        if($data->status==0){
            return SwitchInput::widget([
                'name' => 'status_11',
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'size' => 'mini',
                    'onColor' => 'success',
                    'offColor' => 'danger',
                    'onText' => 'Active',
                    'offText' => 'Inactive',
                ],
                'value' => true,
            ]);
        }
        else if($data->status==1){
            return SwitchInput::widget([
                'name' => 'status_11',
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'size' => 'mini',
                    'onColor' => 'success',
                    'offColor' => 'danger',
                    'onText' => 'Active',
                    'offText' => 'Inactive',
                ],
                'value' => false,
            ]);;
        }
    }
],
```

You can just pass the value of the `$data->status` to the `value` attribute of the `SwitchInput` rather than using `if(){}else{}`.

Then to implement what you are looking for you have to use the `pluginEvent` option of the `SwitchInput` and bind the `switchChange.bootstrapSwitch` event to send an ajax call whenever the status of the `SwitchInput` is changed so your code for the Griview should look like below

```
<?php
use kartik\switchinput\SwitchInput;

$js = <<< JS
    function sendRequest(status, id){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/controller/action',
            method:'post',
            data:{status:status,id:id},
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error:function(jqXhr,status,error){
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    }
JS;

$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);


echo  GridView::widget(
    [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    
            //'alumni_id',
            'tahun_lulus',
            'file_excel',
            [
                'attribute' => 'status',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($data) {
                    return SwitchInput::widget(
                        [
                            'name' => 'status_11',
                            'pluginEvents' => [
                                'switchChange.bootstrapSwitch' => "function(e){sendRequest(e.currentTarget.checked, $data->id);}"
                            ],
                    
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'size' => 'mini',
                                'onColor' => 'success',
                                'offColor' => 'danger',
                                'onText' => 'Active',
                                'offText' => 'Inactive'
                            ],
                            'value' => $data->status
                        ]
                    );
                }
            ],
            //'deleted',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
    
            [ 'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]
);
```

**Note: just make sure you change the `url:'/controller/action',` to the actual URL and action. If you are not using `prettyUrl` then you must change it to `index.php?r=controller/action`.**

#### Edit

I have updated the code above to pass the `id` of the row along with the `status` to your action in the controller, the action will get the variables like below.

```
public function actionUpdate(){
   $status = Yii::$app->request->post('status');
   $id = Yii::$app->request->post('id');

}
```

Comment: Can you make the example of the controller? I can't pass the `id` (primary_key) of the data to the Javascript.

Comment: @GeraldSihotang i have updated the answer please see.