# Transfer of date to the database

Tags: mysql, yii2

the beginner in Yii, connected DatePicker in GridView, but when I set date, in the Database nothing changes, there are old values. I do not understand how to make so that data came to the Database.

View:

```
    <?= GridView::widget([

            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => [
                'avito_login',
                'avito_password',
                'Region',
                "City",
                "legal_entity",
                "manager_contact_phone",
                "avito_user_id",
                "teg",

        [
            'label' => 'Date begin subscription',
            'value' => function ($model, $key, $value) {
                return \kartik\date\DatePicker::widget([
                    'name' => 'date_subscription',
                    'model' => $model,
                    'value' => $model->date_subscription,
                    'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INPUT,
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                        'autoclose' => true,
                    ],
'pluginEvents'=>[
                'changeDate'=>"function(e) {[jQuery.ajax({ url: '/admin/clients/date-subscription', type: 'post', contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', dataType: 'html', data: { data: this.value }, success: function (data) { alert(data) });
                                 }",
                           ],
                   ]);
                         },
            'format' => 'raw',
        ],

    ?>
```

Controller

```
public function actionDateSubscription()
{

    $datesubscription = Yii::$app->request->post('date_subscription');
}
```

Nothing occurs, fields with date stopped being active

Comment: not clear what you are trying to ask,? are you saying that your update to the selected column `date_subscription` in database is not reflected in the `GridView`? OR are you trying to update the database using the select2 dropdown that is populated in the `Gridview` when an option is selcted ?

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam: I have a table where there is a column with dates which can be set by means of DatePicker. But when I set new value of date, in the Database it does not change. I want to learn how to make so that the value of date in the database changed too

Comment: and that `DatePicker` you are talking about is in the GridView right?

Comment: Yes. Added the GridView code where I take out it

Comment: ok basically you need to have an ajax call bind to the datepicker which sends the data to the `controller/action` where you update and then refresh the gridview to reflect the changes, you can find a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128417/yii2-update-data-by-switch-toogle-using-ajax-pjax-in-gridview/55131789#55131789) which uses the toggle switch to update , you can follow that answer to implement and if you run into troubles you can update your question with the error you are receiving

Comment: Ok man, thanks. I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to bind an ajax call to the `datepicker` which sends the `date` to the server `controller/action` which updates the new date into the database and sends the response back to the frontend, where if everything is OK it refreshes the gridview to reflect the new date.

**[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128417/yii2-update-data-by-switch-toogle-using-ajax-pjax-in-gridview/55131789#55131789)** is a similar answer which uses toggle-switch to update the database `status` column, you can have the general idea about the process.

The only thing that is different in your case is that you have to use the `pluginEvents` option to specify the `changeDate` event and bind the ajax call to that event like below

```
[
    'label' => 'Date begin subscription',
    'value' => function ($model, $key, $value) {
        return \kartik\date\DatePicker::widget([
            'name' => 'date_subscription',
            'model' => $model,
            'value' => $model->date_subscription,
            'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INPUT,
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                'autoclose' => true,
            ],
            'pluginEvents'=>[
                'changeDate'=>"function(e) { //call your ajax fuction here }",
            ]
        ]);
    },
    'format' => 'raw',
],
```

Note: if you have aloowed `date_subscription` to be empty/null then make sure you call the ajax in the `clearDate` event too along with the `changeDate`.

For a complete list of events See the [DOCS](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html)

Comment: 'pluginEvents'=>[
                'changeDate'=>"function(e) { jQuery.ajax({
                     url: '/controller/action',
                     type: 'post',
                     contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                     dataType: 'html',
                     data: {
                         data: this.value
                     },
                     success: function (data) {
                         alert(data);
                     },
I probably not correctly wrote function, but did not work(

Comment: @KevinSmash you should add the info in your question by editing and the code does not look complete , it has multiple missing `}` . also you need to change the `controller/action` to the actual `controller` and `action` name where you will submit the request. also please describe what error do you get when you change the date any errors in the console?