# Kartik Gridview Switch inputType

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

I've been looking into this all day, and I'm just wondering if there is built in functionality for Kartik EditableColumn in regards to inputType.

While one can easily apply the SwitchInput to filterType - I can't seem to find a way to handle it in column. It is simply a boolean that I would like handled by this toggle.

While this code produces what I am looking for (aesthetically), I can't produce the expected functionality without strapping it to some JS.

```php
    [
        //'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'label' => 'Public',
        'hAlign' => 'center',
        'vAlign' => 'middle',
        'mergeHeader' => true,
        'format' => 'raw',
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return SwitchInput::widget([
                'name' => 'test',
                'value' => $model->public,
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'size' => 'mini',
                    'onText' => 'ON',
                    'offText' => 'OFF',
                ],
                'labelOptions' => ['style' => 'font-size: 12px;'],
            ]);
        }
    ],
```

Produces:
[image]

Comment: are you trying to update a record in the database by using toggle switch?

Comment: yes i am @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yii2 - Update data by switch toogle using Ajax/Pjax in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128417/yii2-update-data-by-switch-toogle-using-ajax-pjax-in-gridview) , this should help you out with the js part implementation by using the `switchChange.bootstrapSwitch` event under the `pluginEvents` option and update the record

Comment: that is exactly what ive been looking for. Thank you much! @MuhammadOmerAslam